# How to check particular app is already installed on android or iphone device or not?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I make an application in react-native where I listed the app install campaign. I can't find the solution to track, the app is installed or not on the user device.

I also tried "react-native-check-app-install" this but it's not working at all.

Comment: What's the error with check-app-install, if you shared some code we might be able to help with that.

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_appList.APP_LIST[key].pkgName'). I this package is not for checking an app, its only for the app that listed in app.json